# ImportError: No module named twisted.internet

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I installed python 2.7.5 which is working fine.

I then install scrapy (which, I think, uses twisted internally).  My scrapy spider is also working fine.

I installed twisted:

> sudo apt-get install python-twisted

Then, I created a sample program using Echo Server code shown [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

Here is the code

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor


class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

reactor.listenTCP(1234, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I try to run this code using this command:

```
$ python twistedTester.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twistedTester.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet
```

Can anyone help me with how I can debug why my twisted package is not being picked up by Python installation?

Comment: Try running `which python` - what does it tell you?  What about `which python2.7`?  How about `python -c "import twisted; print(twisted)"`?  Do you perhaps have a file called `twisted.py` somewhere on `sys.path`?

Answer (score 20):

If you use [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) just try:

```
pip install twisted
```

The same works with w3lib and lxml.

On some *nix systems this might give you a permission error. If that happens, try:

```
sudo -H pip install twisted
```

Comment: This worked for me, also, note, on mac os X it may say "error 1:permission denied" unless sudo is used.  "sudo pip install twisted"

Answer (score 9):

I figured out why this error was happening.  For some reason, using `apt-get` to install a python package was not installing it right.

So, I had to download a tar ball and install the package from them.

I downloaded Twisted tar from [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/Releases/Twisted/13.1/Twisted-13.1.0.tar.bz2).

I did a `tar xjf Twisted-13.1.0.tar.bz2` - this created a directory called **Twisted-13.1.0**

next, `cd Twisted-13.1.0`
Finally, `python setup.py install`

This gave me an error.  Twisted required another package called zope.interface.  So, I downloaded tar ball for zope.interface from [here](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/python-zope-interface/zope.interface-3.6.1.tar.gz/7a895181b8d10be4a7e9a3afa13cd3be/).  Then, ran this command `tar xzf zope.interface-3.6.1.tar.gz`  That created a folder called **zope.interface-3.6.1**.  So, cd into zope.interface-3.6.1 and run `python setup.py install`

Note:  Depending on your user's rights, you may want to do these commands in sudo mode.  Just add the keyword sudo before every command.

Comment: `apt-get install python-twisted` generally always works.  If it doesn't, you should send a detail bug report to your distro team (either Debian or Ubuntu, it seems) so they can fix this.  The will need more detail than "not installing it right" though.

Comment: sudo python setup.py install

Comment: This worked for me but Milev's answer didn't work. I am on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 7):

please rename the file **twisted.py** to something else. whenever you import a function from a file the interpreter will search for the file in the current location and then it searches in the library. so if you have any file in the name of "**twisted.py**" you should probably rename it.

after renaming it. dont fail to remove the **twisted.pyc** file before running it again.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me too. Finally I figure out that there is a file named `twisted.py` my present working directory. I removed `twisted.py` and `twisted.pyc`. Problem resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Twisted may have removed the `twisted.internet` module from the current release. Pinning on [the version required by `scrapy` (17.9.0)](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/setup.py#L66) worked for me:

```sh
$ pip install twisted==17.9.0
```

Checking if it's installed:

```sh
$ python -c "import twisted.internet; print(twisted.internet)"
<module 'twisted.internet' from '/Users/username/dev/env/redacted-ewmlD2h2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/__init__.py'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why `apt-get install python-twisted` was not enough or "installing it right", as you said, user1700184.

I use Debian Wheezy and Python 2.7.

I just had to move the folder named "twisted" from `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` to `/usr/lib/python2.7/`

The same has to be done with the package "zope" and any other one that you do install but is not retrieved when you try run your code.

However, why this is even necessary in my case is still a mystery since my `sys.path` does include both `/usr/lib/python2.7/` and `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, so whatever was under `dist-packages` should have been retrieved by the interpreter.

Comment: Do not move packages around in `/usr`.  Something on your system is broken; this is a bug in debian.  Please report the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worth noting that if you use sudo to launch python you are using your original default system python. This is **NOT** the python that your `PATH` points to. For example if you are using Anaconda and you have updated your path such that `which python` points to `path/to/anaconda/bin/python`, `sudo which python` will still point to `usr/bin/python`.

So obviously `sudo python twistedTester.py` will not find the twisted module. To get around this you should explicitly pass the path to the anaconda python. Like so:

```
sudo path/to/anaconda/bin/python twistedTester.py
```