# Missing (built-in) Twisted modules after upgrading Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Are there any issues when updating the Python version on a Unix system in terms of dependencies that might not carry over?  I've got an SLES 11 system that comes with Python 2.6, need to update to Python 2.7.3.  After I go through the update, I have scripts that need to utilized the "twisted" module which I believe should come included.  Instead I'm still seeing the error

```
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet
```

I've installed using both "make install" and "make altinstall" on different occasions and they're both running into the same issue.

Comment: Twisted is not a builtin module.

Comment: Then what am I seeing under both /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted and /usr/lib64/python/site-packages/twisted ?

Comment: That's way you should always upgrade/install using the packages manager on Linux and not manual upgrading.

Comment: You're seeing a third-party module.  `site-packages` doesn't just contain builtin modules, it contains any extra modules you installed.  You'll have to install Twisted yourself, for which you can find instructions by googling.

Comment: Did you look at this?  There are many other topics with the same issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476761/importerror-no-module-named-twisted-internet

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I don't know where I misread that it was a builtin module.