# Python imports wrong version of library outside of virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, twisted

Need help updating a python package.

I have an implementation that requires the following import

```
from twisted.internet.ssl import optionsForClientTLS
```

"optionsForClientTLS" was added to the twisted framework with version 14(?). I think the non-virtualenv import is getting a dated version-- If that import is within a virtualenv that has twisted installed via pip, everything is fine. Import fails outside the virtualenv.

In the virtualenv

```
twistd --version
```

Shows 15.2.1. On the bare system it shows 13.2.0.

```
pip install twisted
....
pip freeze
```

shows

```
Twisted==15.2.1
```

Uninstalling twisted using pip and reinstalling didn't help. You can install twisted from apt-get using

```
sudo apt-get install python-twisted
```

and it installs the older version, but after purging it and installing using only pip I still get the older version.

[Possibly related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476761/importerror-no-module-named-twisted-internet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue in a terrible way. It was a few days ago, so the paths may not be exactly right.

The assumption that there were two python packages was correct (I think.) I suspect the order of the paths in PYTHONPATH meant that the wrong version was being imported first, while pip was installing in a version that was later on in the path.

My "solution" was to copy the twisted directory from the up to date version to the older version. This was either from `usr/local/lib/python...` to `usr/lib/python...` or from `... site-packages` to `... dist-packages.` I can check again if someone has the same issue and can't resolve it.

Comment: Why are you installing a different version of Twisted onto your base system?  This what virtualenv is for; install the version you want in the virtualenv and then run it from the virtualenv.

Comment: I need to distribute the resulting package through pypi, and requiring virtualenv to make sure everything works is not enough.

Comment: Are you saying you want a continuous integration system to do system installs?  In that case you might want to use something like Docker for isolation.  Do you do something unusual with distutils where it will behave differently on a system installation vs. a virtualenv?

Comment: No, I just want to be sure pip install for our package (generally) works outside a virtualenv. In my case here I was trying to remove or upgrade the existing version so I could use v15.

Its a CLI tool. While its not a huge burden, Id like it if users didn't have to use a virtualenv for the sake of usability.